# Extract member info from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-filters

I am trying to get all data from my Google Analytics account to a database using their Reporting API v4. In the below request and response, I see a number in the `values` attribute. I want to get member specific data for that number? For example, `value` is 65 for dimension `20130101`. I want to get data of those 65 members that accessed my website that day (2013-01-01 - the specified dimension in the request). Any data that GA has will suffice. For example, the Gender of those 65 members, their session Id, age etc.

**Google Analytics Reporting API Request:**

```
{
"reportRequests": [
    {
        "viewId": "345",
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "daysAgo",
                "endDate": "yesterday"
            }
        ],

        "metrics": [
            {
                "expression": "ga:users"
            }
        ],
        "dimensions":[
            {
              "name":"ga:date"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

**Response**

```
{
"reports": [
    {
        "columnHeader": {
            "dimensions": [
                "ga:date"
            ],
            "metricHeader": {
                "metricHeaderEntries": [
                    {
                        "name": "ga:users",
                        "type": "INTEGER"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "20130101"
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "65"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "20130102"
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "69"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "20130103"
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "48"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "totals": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        "490"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "rowCount": 3,
            "minimums": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        "44"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "maximums": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        "94"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "isDataGolden": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics reporting api don't provide single rows reports, that means that all the data that you can collect is gruped by the dimension.

In that case, if you want to retrieve al this data in a single report, you have to implement a custom dimension to a users level to identify each one, one option is send the client id (the _ga cookie) to the platform and add that dimension

Here is a good post of how to implement this
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-clientid-to-custom-dimension-gtag-js/

Have in mind that you can expect others on the reports in that case, due the high cardinality.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en

For premium users you can export the data via BigQuery

Greetings

Comment: So when I request data in the custom dimension via the reporting API, my data is going to be sampled?

Comment: not sampled, but you can see a max of 50k of unique values, after that the upcoming values will be displayed as (Other), take in consideration that this is not a solution, this is a workaround, Google Analytics is not designed as a tool to get grouped data not individuals study subject.

Comment: I know the no.of users on my mobile app are less than 50K each week. So if I filter by week, should I expect to see all member data without the (Other) entries?

Comment: yes, if you have more will only see the first 50k rows, if others appears just reduce the time windows to make the (Others) dissapears